# Ошибка при сравнении командой cmp в NASM

Tags: ассемблер, логика

Кусок моей программы:

```
        mov     esi,'Y'
        mov     ecx,    buf1
        cmp     ecx,    esi             ;
        je      met         ;
        jne     tem     ;


tem:     
        mov eax,4                   ;
        mov ebx,1                   ;
        mov ecx,utro                ;
        mov edx,utroLen

met: 
        mov eax,4                   ;
        mov ebx,1                   ;
        mov ecx,den                ;
        mov edx,denLen
```

Строка utro выдает "Доброе утро" а строка den выдает добрый день. При запуске программы, по идее, после ввода Y программа должна выдавать "Добрый день", а после ввода N - "Доброе утро". У меня же она каждый раз выводит "Добрый день".
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Где именно у вас вывод текста? После `mov edx, utroLen` у вас есть переход через следующий блок кода?

Comment: Нет. После куска-завершение программы

Comment: заменить jne на jmp?

Comment: Замена не помогает.

Comment: Понял в чем проблема. Сейчас пофикшу.

Answer (score 1):

```
    mov     esi,'Y'
    mov     ecx,    buf1
    cmp     ecx,    esi             ;
    je      met         ;
    jne     tem     ; Вот эту строку удалить так как она ни чего не делает

tem:     
    mov eax,4                   ;
    mov ebx,1                   ;
    mov ecx,utro                ;
    mov edx,utroLen
Вот сюда добавить jmp after_choise


met: 
    mov eax,4                   ;
    mov ebx,1                   ;
    mov ecx,den                ;
    mov edx,denLen

Вот сюда добавить after_choise:
```

Проблема была в том что после заполнения регистров в первой секции код переходил ко второй и перезатирал регистры.

Я синтаксиса не помню точно, придется поправить самостоятельно.

Answer (score 1):

Начнем с начала:

1. Насколько я знаю, в nasm, как и в fasm, конструкция `mov ecx, buf1` означает запись в ecx адреса буфера (в синтаксисе masm это соответствует `mov ecx, offset buf1`), вам нужно сделать `movzx ecx, byte [buf1]`, т.е. копирование 1 байта из области памяти по адресу `buf1` в 4-байтный регистр с заполнением остальных байт нулями. В этом случае используется `movzx` (ZX - zero extension - "расширение с добиванием нулями") вместо `mov` - т.к. читается из области памяти размером в байт, а записывается в 4-байтный регистр, оставшиеся (старшие) байты необходимо обнулить, чтобы в них не оказалось мусора.

   Другой вариант начала (более простой):

   ```
   mov     cl, [buf1]
   cmp     cl, 'Y'
   je      met
   ```
2. После проверки на равенство не нужно делать проверку на неравенство (если условие на равенство не выполнилось, значит условие на неравенство выполнится и так).
3. В показанном коде отсутствует собственно вызов, отображающий текст. Вам нужно либо вставить его два раза после указания длины строки, при этом после первого вызова нужно сделать `jmp` через последующий блок (иначе у вас отобразится сначала "доброе утро", а потом сразу же "добрый день"):

   ```
           mov     cl, [buf1]
           cmp     cl, 'Y'
           je      met

   tem: ; метку можно удалить, т.к. она не используется
           mov eax,4
           mov ebx,1
           mov ecx,utro
           mov edx,utroLen
           <отобразить текст>
           jmp skip
   met: 
           mov eax,4
           mov ebx,1
           mov ecx,den
           mov edx,denLen
           <отобразить текст>
   skip:
           ...
   ```

   Или нужно сделать один вызов, но после блока, начинающегося с метки `tem`, сделать `jmp` через блок, начинающийся с метки `met`:

   ```
           mov     cl, [buf1]
           cmp     cl, 'Y'
           je      met

           mov eax,4
           mov ebx,1
           mov ecx,utro
           mov edx,utroLen
           jmp display
   met: 
           mov eax,4
           mov ebx,1
           mov ecx,den
           mov edx,denLen
   display:
           <отобразить текст>
   ```