# Nasm неправильный вывод

Tags: ассемблер, сравнение, условия, nasm

***Не могу понять, где делаю ошибку, уже по-разному пробовал, но результат +- одинаковый... Помогите найти ошибку.***

Программа выводит Is it noon? После ввода y программа должна выдавать "Good day!", а после ввода n - "Good morning!". А у меня (уже по-всякому пробовал, но что-то не так всё равно):

Вывод:

```
Is it noon?   
Good morning!  //Почему это выводится?
Good day!      //И это

y

Good day!

ИЛИ

Is it noon?  
Good morning!  //Почему это выводится?
Good day!      //И это

n

Good morning!
Good day!        //Почему-то ещё вывелся вариант для ответа у
```

Код программы:

```
SECTION .data
out: DB 'Is it noon?',10
morning: DB 'Good morning!',10
day: DB 'Good day!',10
outLen: EQU $-out
morningLen: EQU $-morning
dayLen: EQU $-day
SECTION .bss
buf1: RESB 10

SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start
_start:

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,out
mov edx,outLen

int 80h

mov eax,3
mov ebx,0
mov ecx,buf1
mov edx,8

int 80h

mov cl,[buf1]
cmp cl,'y'
je yes

mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,morning
mov edx,morningLen
int 80h
jmp exit

yes:
mov eax,4
mov ebx,1
mov ecx,day
mov edx,dayLen
int 80h

exit:
mov eax,1
mov ebx,0
int 80h
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461752/Ошибка-при-сравнении-командой-cmp-в-nasm              Попробовал воспользоваться советами с этого вопроса, но не помогло...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$-out` значит вычесть адрес `out` из текущего адреса, т.е. получить размер участка памяти начиная с `out` и по текущий адрес.

В качестве текущего во всех трех случаях у вас выступает один и тот же адрес.

Таким образом `outLen` содержит длину строки

```
"Is it noon?\nGood morning!\nGood day!\n"
```

`morningLen` – строки

```
"Good morning!\nGood day!\n"
```

а `dayLen` – строки

```
"Good day!\n"
```

перенесите метки следующим образом

```
out: DB 'Is it noon?',10
outLen EQU $-out
morning: DB 'Good morning!',10
morningLen EQU $-morning
day: DB 'Good day!',10
dayLen EQU $-day
```